# How to generate data dictionary and SQL queries from Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

My local `sqlite` database is encrypted (created by `SQLAlchemy().create_all()`) and I can't get into it via `sqlite` command line. I would like to know if it is possible to write down some code to extract the **data dictionary** out of SQLAlchemy defined models. Or rather, I appreciate the same if there is a way to generate the whole SQL queries that it used to create the sqlite file. Thanks!